# CakePHP remove favicon

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Inside my layout file default.ctp I have comment the line

```
echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
```

but the cake favicon still show up on browser tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your browser cache and if the icon is still loading delete the file `favicon.ico` in the subfolder `/webroot/` of your CakePHP app (or replace it by your own favicon).

Comment: So check the HTML output (in browser > right click > source) - is there still a favicon meta tag in the HTML header included? if not I'm pretty sure the icon is still in your browser cache. Delete cache and restart your browser...

Comment: there is no meta tag in the inspect element @user1843159

Comment: Have you checked if there is a favicon.ico file in webroot and removed it as suggested?

Comment: oh , now it's working. As you mention it's all about cache. Thanks so much for your answer @user1843159